# Cname entry for podcast.mydomain.com is resolving to the desired location cloud.podbean.com but ssl isn't working

Tags: ssl, cname-record

I have a domain: mydomain.com. It is hosted in Cpanel/WHM and I installed a regular SSL certificate on the server (comodo SSL). I added a cname entry to point "podcast" to https://cloud.podbean.com.

Visiting https://example.com works, but when I try to access the https://podcast.example.com

What am I doing wrong? Is this not possible to get it to work? Someone suggested I use a load balancer but, to be honest, I'm not very knowledgeable about managing the server. I use a VPS with root access and have to hack my way through stuff. Any help on clarifying this issue is truly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://help.podbean.com/support/solutions/articles/25000008125-setting-up-my-own-domain-with-ssl-certification-for-my-podbean-podcast

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation is not really clear enough to answer, but I'll just mention that a certificate is only valid when the site name matches *exactly*, and subdomains are not an exact match (unless you use a wildcard certificate).

A certificate for `example.com` is ***not*** valid for `podcast.example.com`.

Comment: Massimo, thanks for the answer! I guess my real question now is will a wildcard ssl secure/encrypt the cname entry?  Or will I need to set up something like cloudflare? I haven't used that but looks really expensive for what we're trying to do.

Comment: A wildcard certificate will be valid for **all** subdomains. If you only need `podcast.example.com`, get a certificate with *that* name. Or you can get a SAN certificate with two names, `example.com` and `podcast.example.com`.